# Пропадает фокус с JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

Нашел [реализацию для автокомплита](http://www.algosome.com/articles/java-jcombobox-autocomplete.html) для `JComboBox`. Все работает вроде хорошо, но есть одна проблема. Если добавлять данную реализацию на панель или фрейм, где имеются кнопки или еще какие-нибудь поля для ввода, то после ввода первого символа в данную версию `JComboBox` фокус перепрыгивает на другой элемент гуи, будь-то кнопка или поле.

Как сделать так, чтобы фокус оставался на данном `JComboBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте tc.requestFocus(); в реализацию AutocompleteJComboBox. После строк

```
.........................
for (String s : founds) {
    addItem(s);
}
setEditable(true);
setPopupVisible(true);
//Вот тут
tc.requestFocus();
}
.........................
```

Там ниже, в комментах к примеру обсуждается данное решение(см. 4 коммент сверху)

Comment: Да, спасибо) не посмотрел внимательно комментарии)

Comment: не за что) Успехов